# Turn off validation if field is disabled

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I'm using SmartGWT LGPL. I would like to turn off validation for fields that are disabled.
In picture below there is scenario when 'Absolute time' is disabled because 'Relative' option is selected. 'Absolute time' field validation should not raise validation error in this case.

[image]

I'm using validators that are provided for me from a server side, so I'm unable to alter them. I was trying to do it like this:

```
boolean valid = view.getValuesManager().validate();
if (!valid) {
    view.getValuesManager().showErrors();
    Map errors = view.getValuesManager().getErrors();
    for (Iterator<String> it = errors.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        String key = it.next();
        if (view.getValuesManager().getItem(key).getDisabled()) {
        // disabled fields should not be validated
            view.getValuesManager().clearFieldErrors((String)key, false);
            it.remove();
        }
    }
    valid = errors.isEmpty();
 }
```

but when I invoke:

```
 view.getValuesManager().saveData(..)
```

SmartGWT it is validating again and save operation is aborted.
Is there a way to turn off validation for disabled fields or turn it off for saveData operation?